# Непонятный участок кода PHP

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!

Кто поможет разъяснить следующий участок кода:

```
call_user_func_array(array($this->redis, 'zunionstore'), $args);

$usersActivity = $this->_activity($usersKey, $num, $before, $after);
return $usersActivity;
```

В данном примере не понятно, что делает **call_user_func_array**, почему первый аргумент массив данных, а не имя вызываемой функции.

```
$args // Array;
$this->redis // Object $this->redis = new Redis();
zunionstore // Не понятно
```

Comment: Вот же [про коллбэки](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.callable.php) — если нужно вызывать не ф-ю, а метод объекта, то передается `array( объект, название метода)`

Comment: @Sergiks опередили :)

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk в моём ответе есть ссылка, содержащая в себе примеры :)

Comment: Я так понимаю, что вызывается функция `$this->redis->zunionstore()` и ей передаются аргументы `$args`

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, точно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Массив, потому что вызывается метод `$this->redis->zunionstore()`. Смотрите 3-й пример на стр. [Callbacks](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.callable.php).

Если указать просто имя функции (напр., `strlen`), то PHP искал бы такую функцию в глобальной области.

Comment: *хм :) только увидел ветку комментов под вопросом..*

Answer (score 1):

```
call_user_func_**array**()
```

так внимательно всмотритесь в название функции :)

либо откройте мануал http://php.net/manual/ru/function.call-user-func-array.php

Comment: Неправда. ``array``, на который вы указали, говорит скорее о втором параметре.